# How to change the content of "This field is required" in Jquery form validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

How can I change the general message of "This field is required" in Jquery form validation plugin to "このフィールドは必須です"? The color of the message can be changed by using the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
label.error {color: red;}

</style>
```

But how to change the content?

I want to change all "This filed is required" messages.

I want to change all "required" messages to "このフィールドは必須です".

```
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
     name: "required",
     email: {
       required: true,
       email: true
     }
   },
   messages: {
     name: "Please specify your name",
     email: {
       required: "We need your email address to contact you",
       email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
     }
   }
})
```

only changes specific message for specific rule and specific element.

I wrote

```
 messages: { 
        required:"このフィールドは必須です"

        }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `messages` object has several interesting attributes to adjust:

```
messages: {
    required: "This field is required.",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    ...
}
```

See [the source](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.js).

These can be set as defaults via the `setDefaults()` method:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    messages: {
        required: "このフィールドは必須です"
    }
});
```

Comment: you should reconsider changing accepted answer to answer below $.validator.messages.required = "Your new required message here!";

Answer (score 24):

I tried the accepted answer and it did not work for me at all. I did more searching on Google and found [this article](http://hallodom.posterous.com/jquery-validate-how-to-change-error-message).

Using this line of code solved my problem:

```
$.validator.messages.required = "Your new required message here!";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the messages option in the [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) method.