# jQuery validation plugin: How to create your own messages

Tags: php, jquery, validation, plugins

I am using jquery validation plugin with php on ubuntu.

I am applying validation on my forms like this:

```
$(obj).find("form").validate();
```

When I set "email" as class of any text field and I give it a wrong formated email address, it show the following error like this.

```
Please enter a valid email address.
```

**Question:** Above message is very lengthy and damage the alignment of my form and table. I want to use very short messages like this.

```
required
invalid email
invalid phone number
etc.
```

I have tried this but it is showing its own messages not mine.

```
$(obj).find("form").validate({

        messages: {
            required: "Required.",
            email: "Invalid email",
            url: "Invalid URL."
        }

    });
```

can any one tell me how should I do this? What is the exact code. "Messages" option is not working for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are the names of your input elements? See how the key in messages object relates to `name` attribute of the `input` element not to the name of the class. **This is crucial**

```
<form id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input id="iname" name="nname" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" /><br />
        <input id="iemail" name="nemail" size="25"  class="required email" /><br />
        <input id="iurl" name="nurl" size="25"  class="url" /><br />
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#commentForm").validate({
        messages: {
            nname: "Required",
            nemail: "Invalid email",
            ncomment: "Invalid URL"
        }
    });
});
```

You can also specify different messages for different errors

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
    messages: {
        nname: "Required",
        nemail: {
            required: "Email needed",
            email: "Invalid email"
        },
        ncomment: "Invalid URL"
    }

});
```

Comment: Perfect. The real thing is 'name' of the field when using 'messages' option.  I was using class for this and that is my mistake. Thanks. your answer is accepted :)

Comment: Would any of you happen to know if there is a way to attach message copy in an HTML attribute, such as `class="required"` or `minlength="2"`? The documentation for the message option hints at using the "title" attribute, but that does not seem to work. This is the only common option one needs to write new JS for and I am trying to use this plugin to eliminate additional config and setup for each new form added to a given site. 

Thanks!

Comment: @jozecuervo http://jsfiddle.net/nDNYP/ But the title can only hold 1 error message. Using title you can't show different messages for different errors

Answer (score 1):

Messages option should work. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838695/how-to-change-the-content-of-this-field-is-required-in-jquery-form-validation-p).

Comment: question edited: I am using messages option as described in my question but it is showing its own messages. can you tell me the exact syntax. thanks

Comment: Please see the linked question and accepted answer. Probably the setDefaults method is the best solution for you.